# Geb EmptyNavigator is not present

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, geb

Using Geb 0.13.1 here. I'm not trying to integrate it with any kind of testing framework (yet), just trying to get a feel for its DSL. I just want Geb to launch a Firefox browser, point it to Google's homepage and type in 'gmail' in the search address (HTML `<input/>` with an id of '`q`'):

```
class GoogleHomepage extends Page {
    static url = 'http://google.com'

    static at = {
        title == 'Google'
    }

    static content = {
        search {
            $('input#q')
        }
    }
}

class MyGebDriver {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        FirefoxDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver()
        Browser browser = new Browser(driver: firefoxDriver)

        Browser.drive(browser) {
            to(GoogleHomepage)

            search.value('gmail')

            quit()
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, Firefox opens up and goes to Google, but seems to choke when finding the search ('`q`' element) bar to set a value for:

```
Exception in thread "main" geb.error.RequiredPageContentNotPresent: The required page
    content 'sandbox.geb.GoogleHomepage -> search: geb.navigator.EmptyNavigator' is not
    present
```

Any ideas as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an EmptyNavigator because you're looking for an input with an id of q $('input#q') try $('input[name=q]') instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your GoogleHomepage looks a bit goofy to me. 
What if you made it look more like this which follows the geb dsl better.

```
class GoogleHomepage extends Page {

    url = 'http://google.com'

    static at = {
        waitFor() {
            title == 'Google'
            content
        }
    }

   static content = {
       search(required: true) { $('input#lst-ib') }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @zypherman (+1) - but even with your changes, same exact exception.

Comment: It appears as if Deon above is correct. If you look at the DOM on Google's homepage you can see that the search input doesn't have an id of q. The id is actually 'lst-ib'. If you'd like to use the name=q then use the selector above. Otherwise you can use $("input#lst-ib").

Comment: I updated my above example to include the proper id as well as made the at checker method a little better. It's important to tell Geb to wait for the page to be loaded and all elements you require to be present. Otherwise you will be attempting to interact with dom that isnt fully rendered.